# How can I query the entire schema that is stored inside of a datomic database?

Tags: datomic

I have a datomic database that I have updated with multiple schemas. I am looking to get the entire schema back as a map seperating each schema. This is the query I have currently: 
`(d/q '[:find ?id
       :where [:db.part/db :db.install/attribute ?p]
              [?p :db/ident ?id]] db)`

Answer (score 3):

You want to query to find everything with `:db.install/attribute`, you can see an example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benkamphaus/e5e85def4c08afae4591) as well as the [datomic java examples](https://github.com/Datomic/datomic-java-examples/blob/master/src/PrintSchema.java#L47-L53) repo on github.

I've reproduced the example from the gist here:

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d] 'clojure.pprint)

;; You can run this with bin/run in the $DATOMIC_DIR
(println "Printing database schema...")
(def conn (d/connect (first *command-line-args*))) ;; call with db-uri as arg

; Find and pretty-print each attribute in schema 
(let [db (d/db conn)]
  (clojure.pprint/pprint
    (map #(->> % first (d/entity db) d/touch)
      (d/q '[:find ?v
             :where [_ :db.install/attribute ?v]]
         db))))
```